# showing list in a animated circle and than after 2 rotates it transform a list

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

is it possible to display a list icons in circle and after 1,2 rotations it will back to the list view..
[image: like first it should be a rotating circle]

and when it forms after 1,2 rotation it should be a line.

[image: like this line]

in short, a css3 animation way to or keyframe or jquery animation :

[image: like first it should be a rotating circle] this to this [image: like this line]..

any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible! and No I will not code it for you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, SO is not a code writing service. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith bro you dont have to.. see the question again. i asked is it possible. did you see anything that i say please code for me.. please please please.. 
well, i do know now that i should do this by jquery and css keyframes thats all i need to know ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like [this](http://codepen.io/Iulius90/pen/WwjrVK) ?

```
...
```